# ListCellRenderer returning Null pointer

Tags: java, listcellrenderer

this is my first post here so apologies in advance if it is horrible...

I'm trying to add items from a list of custom classes into a JList using a custom ListCellRenderer. Each  has a variety of things I would like to add to a row, with a new row being taken for each  in the list:

---

```
    public class MatchRecord {
    private String player;
    private Integer kills;
    private Integer deaths;
    private Integer assists;//getters + setters etc etc below}
```

---

```
private class GameStatistics{//this is the main class of the program

        listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        jList.setModel(listModel);
        listModel.clear(); //get rid of any junk in the list before loading
        recordJList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);

        //add the records to the JList
        recordJList.setCellRenderer(new RecordListRenderer());

        List<MatchRecord> list = new ArrayList();
        list.addAll(recordSet); //recordSet is a Set<MatchRecord> which has been previously loaded from file

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getPlayer()); //this is NOT NULL!
            listModel.addElement(list.get(i));
        }
}
```

---

```
    public class RecordListRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];

    public RecordListRenderer(){
        setOpaque(true);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));

        //set font size + colour here
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
            Object r,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus){

        MatchRecord record = (MatchRecord) r;

        labels[0].setText(record.getPlayer()); //This line returns a null pointer
        labels[1].setText(record.getKills());
        labels[2].setText(record.getDeaths());
        labels[3].setText(record.getAssists());
    return this}
```

I sout the content of the list to make sure it is not null, but the line highlighted above returns a null pointer.

My knowledge of Java is still limited, so any (simple!) help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize your array of `JLabel`s:

```
private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];
```

But you never fill this array with values, so they will be `null` when you want to access them. Set each element with `new JLabel()` and they won't be `null` when you need them.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! The null pointer error is no more, but now the JList is appearing empty?

Comment: I have answered my own question — I was missing an add(labels[i]); line. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];
```

Here is the error. You don't initialize any label in the array.